# finding the maximum date from an array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a mutable array with objects as dates,now i want to get the maximum date from an array..i tried like this

```
NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
for (int i = 0; i<dateArray2.count; i++)
{
    [arrDates addObject:[df dateFromString:dateArray2[i]]];
     }
     NSLog(@"%@",arrDates);
NSDate *maxDate=[arrDates valueForKeyPath:@"@max.date"];
NSLog(@"max date is %@",maxDate);
}
```

while executing app has got terminate..can any one help me...thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error? Stack trace?

Comment: Have you tried `@max.self` instead of `@max.date`?

Comment: do u want to pick the latest date@shaik tamim

Comment: Okay i ll send the code try it. It worked for me.

Comment: just now i tried...@max.self .. i got it...thq..santa :) and Dinesh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

```
NSDate *maxDate = [dateArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

This will give you the largest date from array.

read more  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already iterating the input array, there is no need to build an array of dates; simply keep track of the latest date in the first array:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *latestDate  = [df dateFromString:dateArray2[0]];
for (int i = 1; i<dateArray2.count; i++)
{   
    NSDate *compareDate = [df dateFromString:dateArray2[i]];
    latestDate = [latestDate laterDate:compareDate];
}
NSLog(@"max date is %@",maxDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *arrDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                             ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
arrDates = [[dateArray2 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];

NSString *maxdate=[arrDates objectatindex:0];

sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                             ascending:NO];
```

in this line `@"date"` is your `key` in array